# Weird Linker Error

Tags: c++, linker

For some reason, i get a linker error. my distance.cpp compiles perfectly however same cannot be said for main.cpp this is the error i get:

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Executing  g++.exe...
g++.exe "C:\Users\Himalaya\Desktop\C++\testdistance\main.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Himalaya\Desktop\C++\testdistance\main.exe"    -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\include"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\backward"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include"   -L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib" 
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x13b):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::Distance()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x150):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::setInches(double)'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x16d):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::Distance(int, double)'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x18a):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::Distance(int, double)'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x19c):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::Distance(Distance const&)'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x1af):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::setFeet(int)'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x1c6):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::Distance(Distance const&)'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x1d8):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::Distance(Distance const&)'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x1ea):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::Distance(Distance const&)'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x1fc):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::Distance(Distance const&)'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x3e1):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::Distance(Distance const&)'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x3fc):main.cpp: more undefined references to `Distance::Distance(Distance const&)' follow
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x52a):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::Distance()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x54c):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::operator+(Distance const&)'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x598):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::showDistance()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x5c0):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::showDistance()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x5e8):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::showDistance()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x7f8):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::Distance()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x81a):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::operator-(Distance const&)'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x866):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::showDistance()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x88e):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::showDistance()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x8b6):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::showDistance()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0xac7):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::Distance()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0xb02):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::operator+(Distance const&)'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0xb97):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::showDistance()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0xc3a):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::showDistance()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0xdc9):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::showDistance()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0xe9f):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::getInches()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0xeb6):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::getFeet()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0xfcd):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::Distance()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0xfd8):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::Distance()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0xfe3):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::getInches()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0xff4):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::getFeet()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x101b):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::getInches()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x102c):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::getFeet()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x105d):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::setInches(double)'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x107a):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::setInches(double)'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x10a0):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::showDistance()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x10c8):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::showDistance()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x10f0):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::showDistance()'
C:\Users\Himalaya\AppData\Local\Temp/cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x111b):main.cpp: undefined reference to `Distance::showDistance()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Execution terminated
```

Here is my codes;

distance.cpp

```
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "distance.h"

using namespace std;



Distance::Distance()
{
    feet = 0;
    inches = 0;
}

Distance::Distance(int ft, double in)
{
    this->feet = ft;

    if(in >= 12)
    {
        while(in >= 12) // pull as many feet as possible out of inches
        {
            this->feet += 1;
            in -= 12;
        }
        this->inches = in;  // store remainder
    }
    else
    {
        this->inches = in;
    }
}

Distance::Distance(const Distance &dist)
{
    this->feet = dist.feet;
    this->inches = dist.inches;
}

void Distance::setInches(double in)
{
    if(in >= 12)
    {
        while(in >= 12) // pull as many feet as possible out of inches
        {
            this->feet += 1;
            in -= 12;
        }
        this->inches = in;  // store remainder
    }
    else
    {
        this->inches = in;
    }
}

double Distance::getInches()
{
    return this->inches;
}

void Distance::setFeet(int ft)
{
    this->feet = ft;
}

int Distance::getFeet()
{
    return this->feet;
}

bool Distance::operator==(Distance &dist)
{
    if((this->feet == dist.feet) && (this->inches == dist.inches))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

Distance Distance::operator+(const Distance &dist)
{
    Distance dist_return;
    double total_inches = 0;
    dist_return.feet = this->feet + dist.feet;
    total_inches = this->inches + dist.inches;
    if(total_inches >= 12)
    {
        while(total_inches >= 12) // pull as many feet as possible out of inches
        {
            dist_return.feet += 1;
            total_inches -= 12;
        }
        dist_return.inches = total_inches;
    }
    else
    {
        dist_return.inches = this->inches + dist.inches;
    }

    return dist_return;
}

Distance Distance::operator-(const Distance &dist)
{
    Distance dist_return;
    int temp_feet = this->getFeet(); // copy "this" so we can do math and show properly
    double temp_inches = this->getInches();

    dist_return.feet = temp_feet - dist.feet;
    dist_return.inches = temp_inches - dist.inches;

    dist_return.feet = abs(dist_return.feet);
    dist_return.inches = abs(dist_return.inches);  // distance is never negative, and - means difference, so 12 - 20 = 8

    return dist_return;
}

string Distance::showDistance()
{
    string str_return = "";
    std::ostringstream temp_str_holder;

    if(this->feet > 0)  // only print feet if we have any
    {
        temp_str_holder.str("");  // clear out ostringstream
        temp_str_holder << this->feet;
        str_return += temp_str_holder.str();

        if(this->feet == 1)
        {
            str_return += " foot";
        }
        else
        {
            str_return += " feet";
        }
    }

    if(this->inches > 0)  // only print inches if we have any
    {
        if(this->feet > 0)
        {
            str_return += " ";  // if we have both feet and inches, print spacer between terms
        }

        temp_str_holder.str("");  // clear out ostringstream
        temp_str_holder << this->inches;
        str_return += temp_str_holder.str();

        if(this->inches == 1)
        {
            str_return += " inch";
        }
        else
        {
            str_return += " inches";
        }
    }

    if((this->feet == 0) && (this->inches == 0))  // if 0 feet 0 inches, just say 0 inches
    {
        str_return = "0 inches";
    }

    return str_return;
}
```

distance.h

```
#ifndef DISTANCE_H
#define DISTANCE_H


#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Distance
{
private:
    double inches;
    int feet;

public:
    Distance();
    Distance(int ft, double in);
    Distance(const Distance &dist);
    void setInches(double in);
    double getInches();
    void setFeet(int ft);
    int getFeet();
    bool operator==(Distance &dist);
    Distance operator+(const Distance &dist);
    Distance operator-(const Distance &dist);
    string showDistance();

};

#endif // DISTANCE_H
```

and my main.cpp which the program actually suppose to run from, however it gives me that weird error stated above.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "distance.h"


using namespace std;

void addDistances(Distance dist1, Distance dist2);
void subtractDistances(Distance dist1, Distance dist2);
void sumDistanceArray(Distance dist_array[]);
void plotDistanceArray(Distance dist_array[]);
void calcRectangle(Distance dist1, Distance dist2);
//void calcVolume(Distance dist1, Distance dist2);

int main()
{
    Distance dist1;  // showing initialization using defaults
    dist1.setInches(6.7);
    Distance dist2(1,7);  // showing initialization to a distance
    Distance dist3(0,34);  // showing the auto-conversion of inches to feet as needed
    Distance dist4(dist3);  // showing initialization to another distance object's values
    dist4.setFeet(4);
    Distance dist_array[4] = {dist1, dist2, dist3, dist4};
    int menu_entry;
    bool menu_exit = false;

    do
    {
        //display menu
        cout << endl << endl << endl;
        cout << "***** Main Menu *****" << endl;
        cout << "1: Add two distances" << endl;
        cout << "2: Subtract two distances" << endl;
        cout << "3: Sum an array of distances" << endl;
        cout << "4: Plot an array of distances" << endl;
        cout << "5: Calculate the perimeter and area and volume" << endl;
        cout << "6: Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the number of your selection: ";
        cin >> menu_entry;


        // check entry, warn and promt again if invalid
        if ((menu_entry < 1) || (menu_entry > 6))
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Invalid entry! Please try again." << endl;
            continue;
        }


        switch (menu_entry)
        {
            case 1:
                addDistances(dist2, dist3);
                break;
            case 2:
                subtractDistances(dist2, dist3);
                break;
            case 3:
                sumDistanceArray(dist_array);
                break;
            case 4:
                plotDistanceArray(dist_array);
                break;
            case 5:
                calcRectangle(dist2, dist3);
                break;
            case 6:
            default:
                menu_exit = true;  
                break;
        }
    }
    while(!menu_exit);

    return 0;
}

void addDistances(Distance dist1, Distance dist2)
{
    Distance dist_total;
    dist_total = dist1 + dist2;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "The sum of " << dist1.showDistance() << " and " << dist2.showDistance() << " is "
         << dist_total.showDistance() << endl;
}

void subtractDistances(Distance dist1, Distance dist2)
{
    Distance dist_total;
    dist_total = dist1 - dist2;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "The difference of " << dist1.showDistance() << " and " << dist2.showDistance() << " is "
         << dist_total.showDistance() << endl;
}

void sumDistanceArray(Distance dist_array[])
{
    int i;
    int num_distances = 4;
    Distance dist_total;
    for(i=0; i<num_distances; i++)
    {
        dist_total = dist_total + dist_array[i];
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "The sum of: " << endl;
    for(i=0; i<num_distances; i++)
    {
        cout << dist_array[i].showDistance() << endl;
    }
    cout << "is " << dist_total.showDistance() << endl;
}

void plotDistanceArray(Distance dist_array[])
{
    int i;
    int j;
    double inches;
    double bar_percentage;  
    double bar_length;  
    int num_distances = 4;
    int num_feet_max = 6;  
    int num_max_disp_columns = 60;  

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Plot of the array of distances : " << endl;

    for(i=0; i<num_distances; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(20) << dist_array[i].showDistance() << " ";

        inches = dist_array[i].getInches() + (12 * dist_array[i].getFeet());
        bar_percentage = inches / (num_feet_max*12);
        bar_length = bar_percentage * num_max_disp_columns;  // calculate bar length

        for(j=0; j<(bar_length+1); j++)
        {
            cout << "#";  // draw bar
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void calcRectangle(Distance dist1, Distance dist2)
{
    Distance rect_area;
    Distance rect_perimeter;
    double inches1;
    double inches2;

    inches1 = dist1.getInches() + (12 * dist1.getFeet());
    inches2 = dist2.getInches() + (12 * dist2.getFeet());

    rect_area.setInches(inches1 * inches2);
    rect_perimeter.setInches((2 * inches1) + (2 * inches2));

    cout << endl;
    cout << "A rectangle with dimensions " << dist1.showDistance() << " and " << dist2.showDistance() << " has an area of "
         << rect_area.showDistance() << " and a perimeter of " << rect_perimeter.showDistance() << endl;
}
```

what is the problem? what does cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x13b) mean?? This is something i have not encountered before that is why i am seeking for your help. All these 3 files are in the same folder/path, why does it giving me this error?

Comment: Thanks guys, it was just as simple as adding distance.cpp in my main function. now it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the meaning of `cckxbaaa.o(.text+0x13b)`: that's hackerhead stuff. The important part is the rest of the message: "undefined reference to `Distance::Distance()`" and the rest. It means that the linker hasn't seen the object file that has the `Distance` member functions in it.

Unlike Java, C++ doesn't hunt around your folders to try to figure out what you wanted to use. To compile and link the executable:

```
g++ main.cpp distance.cpp
```

That compresses two steps into one. Step 1: compile each source file into an object file. Step 2: link the object files and the standard library together to produce an executable file. It's that last step that's failing, presumably because the linker command line isn't correct.

Comment: Incidentally, when reading error messages, only read the first one or two. After that they're usually either duplicates or cascades (i.e., the compiler guessed at how to resolve an earlier error and got it wrong, which triggered a later error message). In this case, while the actual messages are different, they are, in fact, the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The linker does not seem to link the compiled object of distance.cpp. So distance.o is missing under the -o options

Check this and compare your linker call

http://homepages.gac.edu/~mc38/2001J/documentation/g++.html

(Another small issue, you do not need to include cmath, sstream and string in the distance.cpp file.